# How to load large video files in html page in a convenient way

Tags: javascript, php, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm working in a web app (php, laravel) that has a heavy video playing work. The video files that are going to be shown are large may be up to 500 to 700 mb.
For some reasons I can't view them as a video tag and give it's src attribute the whole video file link as we do mostly like this

```
// this way is not available for me
<video src="http://www.example.com/media/video_file.mp3" type="video/mp4" ></video>
```

i need to use the way of mediaSource and sourcebuffer and blob urls `URL.createObjectURL(mediaSourceInstance)`
but i can't make the user wait until all the video file is loaded and feed it's blob representation to the media source to start playing the video this is not acceptable by any means because of the large size of videos.

```
// this is the way i mean i want to use or any way similar 
//but it has the disadvantage of waiting until the whole file is loaded

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onload = function() {

    var media = new MediaSource();
    var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
    var buffer = xhr.response;
    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buffer);
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(media);
    videoElement.src = url; 
}

xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.example.com/media/video_file.mp3');

xhr.send();

// this code is only for clarification it may contain bugs
```

my question is:

How to load these video files without making the user wait until all the video file completely downloaded?

Note: i have found an answer but still needs some clarification and i still don't have enough reputation to comment on it so i will include it's link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57419964/11284606) if any one can help clarifying it.

Comment: try to use  <iframe width="420" height="315"
src="http://www.example.com/media/video_file.mp3">
</iframe>

Comment: thank you @MohammadAl-Tamimi for your interest. unfortunately  i can't use i frames like video tags too.

Comment: does the server you're using to host the videos support byte range requests? if so, and the mp4 has the MOOV atom at the start of the file, then things should work as you want...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Node.js Stream API`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, 
                initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
            content="ie=edge"> 
    <title>video player</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <video src="http://localhost:3000/video" controls> 
</video> 
</body> 
</html>
```

```
const http=require('http'); 
const fs=require("fs"); 
const path=require("path"); 

/* http.createServer takes a handler 
function and returns a server instance;*/
const server=http.createServer((req, res)=>{ 
    // return res.end(req.url+req.method); 
    if(req.method==='GET' && req.url==="/"){ 
        /*we will send a index.html page when 
        user visits "/" endpoint*/
        /*index.html will have video component 
        that displays the video*/
        
        fs.createReadStream(path.resolve( 
                        "index.html")).pipe(res); 
        return; 
    } 
    //if video content is requesting 
    if(req.method==='GET' && req.url==="/video"){ 
        const filepath = path.resolve("video.mp4"); 
        const stat = fs.statSync(filepath) 
        const fileSize = stat.size 
        const range = req.headers.range 
        /*when we seek the video it will put 
        range header to the request*/
        /*if range header exists send some 
            part of video*/
        if (range) { 
            //range format is "bytes=start-end", 
            const parts = 
                range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-"); 
            
            const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10) 
            /*in some cases end may not exists, if its 
                        not exists make it end of file*/
            const end = 
                parts[1] ?parseInt(parts[1], 10) :fileSize - 1 
            
            //chunk size is what the part of video we are sending. 
            const chunksize = (end - start) + 1 
            /*we can provide offset values as options to 
        the fs.createReadStream to read part of content*/
            const file = fs.createReadStream(filepath, {start, end}) 
            
            const head = { 
                'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`, 
                'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 
                'Content-Length': chunksize, 
                'Content-Type': 'video/mp4', 
            } 
            /*we should set status code as 206 which is 
                    for partial content*/
            // because video is continuosly fetched part by part 
            res.writeHead(206, head); 
        file.pipe(res); 
            
        }else{ 
        
        //if not send the video from start. 
        /* anyway html5 video player play content 
        when sufficient frames available*/
        // It doesn't wait for the entire video to load. 
        
        const head = { 
            'Content-Length': fileSize, 
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4', 
        } 
        res.writeHead(200, head); 
        fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res); 
        } 
    } 
    /*if anything other than handler routes then send 
    400 status code, is for bad request*/
    else{ 
        res.writeHead(400); 
        res.end("bad request"); 
    } 
}) 

/*check if system has environment variable 
for the port, otherwise defaults to 3000*/
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000; 

//start the server 
server.listen(PORT, () => { 
console.log(`server listening on port:${PORT}`); 
})
```

Comment: thank you @prakhar good solution ,i will try it and mark it as best solution if it worked. But Do you know any alternative of this way with php ?

Comment: I found an example here for loading files chunk by chunk in php --> http://teddy.fr/2007/11/28/how-serve-big-files-through-php/